# Particle Systems & Weight Painting?

Tags: particles, weight-painting

G'day, guys!

Few days ago I stumbled upon one issue that I still can resolve! And I have no any idea how to complete it. I can create feathers as Particle System and use Weight painting to specify certain areas for them to grow on model. But I can't figure out how to make that smooth transition from one color to another!

I use Blender 2.79 only and I pasted here just a random photo from online just to ask this question! 
[image]

So, my question is:
1. How to make feathers with smooth colour transition in Blender? Do we have any possibility to paint over Particle System and particles that are already grow on the model?

Thanx for your time! I really need your help here! Respect to all! :)